# QtOpenGl: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, qtopengl

I installed Deepin Linux few days back. I am trying to install `OpenCv2.4.10` but during compilation I am getting this error:

```
 fatal error: QtOpenGL: No such file or directory
 #include <QtOpenGL>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the compilation of Qt modules for opencv or install Qt with OpenGL support to solve the error